# What does "provides market for something" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Sator: How do you come by your information about the opera?
>
> Protagonist: You wouldn't do business with someone who wasn't savvy
> enough  to be recruited. Hell, the CIA **provides two thirds of the
> market**  for fissile material.
>
> Sator: They're usually buying, not selling.

What does "provides market for something" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To provide a market for" means to be available to buy something. In this example, "provides two thirds of the market for" means they buy two-thirds of what is available.